# Updating a value in root.plist

Tags: ios, settings

If I want to update a value in my root.plist at compile time, such as the version number of the App. Wwhat is the approved method? The root.plist entry looks like:

[image]

I found a previous entry, from 2014, on Stack but don't know if this is still the current approach.
[Update Root.Plist on Compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041085/update-root-plist-on-compile)

Comment: The version number seems to be held as $(MARKETING_VERSION), but how do I inject it into root.plist or extract it from info.plist?

Answer (score 0):

Far too obvious:

The plist values are held in UserDefaults.standard. So matching up the variable names in your plist my example of updating the version would be:

```
func setUserDefaults() {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.setValue("Version 1.23", forKey: "version_preference")
    }
```